# javascript mailto not working in chrome mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mailto

mailto via javascript not working in mobile chrome browser

```
window.location.href = "mailto:linto.cet@gmail.com?subject=subject&body=body"
```

is not working in mobile google chrome browser

[actual source](https://github.com/HedCET/TorrentAlert/blob/master/.polymer/linto/layout-inbox.html#L691)

Comment: what is not working ? the mail action ? the parameters not sended ? ..

Comment: mail client popup is not comimg,

Comment: The  same code work perfectly in desktop chrome browser & inside crosswalk

Comment: Does your console log anything when you run this code?

Comment: How I check console of mobile chrome browser

Answer (score 3):

Chrome on Android is blocking the redirects to apps that are not made via a user gesture.

So via javascript it's not possible to redirect the user to the mail app since Chrome 40, only if you put it for example in a button href, that will work when user clicks the button.

You can read more [in chromium forum](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477456#c5)

If you inspect the Chrome console you will a warning, something like: `Navigation is blocked: mailto:?...`

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer as this is possible.

Create a hidden from view / temporary link element and simulate the click.

```
var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
linkElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
linkElement.style.position = 'absolute';
linkElement.href = 'mailto:linto.cet@gmail.com?subject=subject&body=body';
document.body.appendChild(linkElement);
```

and later when you want to trigger and open the mail client:

```
linkElement.click();
```

Answer (score -2):

On my site, when people click on what they believe to be mailto links (same restrictions apply on tel: links, by the way), I first send a GA event, and then use window.location to initiate the mailto. While Chrome will give me the warning via the dev console, it still processes the tel/mailto request, and the window still pops up.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32356010)