# Manually clicking a link in Android Google Chrome behaves differently than clicking it through code

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, pdf

I have this anchor tag in my html that should download a PDF:

```html
<a id="download" href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf">
  Download
</a>
```

And here is my script:

```js
document.getElementById('download').click();
```

The link works fine, it's downloading the PDF as expected. What I don't get is that in Android Google Chrome (or any other mobile Chromium based browsers), if I press the link manually it opens my PDF Viewer app right away, but if I try to make the code automatically click the link (as in the code above) it only downloads the PDF in background without opening my PDF Viewer app.

The desired behavior should be the first one, as in when I manually press the link it should open the PDF Viewer app. How can I accomplish that by code too? Any ideas why does this happen?

You can check the behavior on this link: https://802753.playcode.io

Or check the snippet here: https://playcode.io/802753

If that's the intended behavior, could anyone point me to any resource about it? I don't know where else to search...

Comment: I tried your link, the file is downloaded automatically, but I get no prompt from chrome to open the file in any pdf viewer app. So I confirm the behaviour. I believe that is a chromium specific the way it behaves for automatically downloaded files( that do not require user inputs to begin the download).

Comment: @Armaggheddon I just wish there could be any resource talking about that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, just like @Armaggheddon said, it's an intended Android Chromium behavior as you can see in these links: [javascript mailto not working in chrome mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649771/javascript-mailto-not-working-in-chrome-mobile-browser/34528227#34528227) and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477456#c5

Because they're too old (2014-2015), I welcome any news you guys may have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<a [attr.href]="link" download="filename.pdf">Download</a>
```

else

```
<a (click)="download(link)" >Download</a>

public download(link){
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = link;
          a.target = "_blank";
          a.download = link.split('/').pop();
          document.body.append(a);
          a.click();
          document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Comment: It still downloads in background :(